# Flip model swap chain doesn't acknowledge menu bar

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, direct3d11, dxgi

I'm trying to change my program from using a bitblt model swap chain (those created with DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD, the default used by most samples), to a flip model swap chain (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL), because it's much faster.

The problem is, the app has a menu bar, and D3D is treating coordinates as relative to the window's client area (as if the window didn't have a menu bar). It doesn't draw on top of the menu bar, but rather, the menu bar obstructs whatever is drawn below it. This doesn't happen with the DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD swap chain.

Another weird thing is, when I resize the window (manually while the app is running), it will sometimes render correctly, with the top left coordinate starting just after the menu bar.

Platform info: Direct3D 11.1, Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 (C++)

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Have you tried ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD``? The ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP*`` modes are intended for CoreWindow/DirectComposition swap chains, although on Windows 10 you have to use them with DirectX 12 so they do work with Windows classic desktop apps at least on Windows 10.

Comment: It worked fine for both DX11 and DX12 to use ``DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL`` for Windows classic desktop app on Windows 10 (14393). I'll try to see if I can get a Windows 8.1 machine to try.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Yes, it works fine with DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD. Many thanks for testing it, I'll await your reply.

Comment: Are you passing the menu properties to [`AdjustWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665(v=vs.85).aspx)? It should correct for the menu area.

Comment: @MooseBoys That wouldn't work unfortunately. The problem isn't with setting the window size, it's about Direct3D not treating coordinates correctly when the window has a menu.

Comment: I can't repro this problem on Windows 8.1 either (at least on a VM).